# How to Remove a row using checkbox in a CustomListView

Tags: android

i want to remove a a row using checkbox in a CustomListView when click on a button then the row should be removed.i have wasted a couple of hours while working on it.Can you please help me..

Comment: remove arraylist item from selected checkbox position and notify list.

Comment: sir i need code.

Comment: first of all put your code i will check what do you do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create checkBox inside listView item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:buttonTint="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>


  //OtherViews

</LinearLayout>
```

after that In your custom Adapter class, create a member variable and its setter method which will called to make checkBox visible once we longClick on any listView item.

Also you have to use ViewHolder inside your custom adapter class to keep track of checked rows otherwise while selecting rows, when you scroll though the listView,rows state will not be saved once goes beyond screen view..

```
 private int checkboxVisibility = View.GONE;

    public void setCheckboxVisibility(int visibility) {
        this.checkboxVisibility = visibility;
    }
 class ViewHolder {

        protected CheckBox checkBox;

        //othercode here

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, viewHolder.checkBox);

            //other views goes here


        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // This line is important.
        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position); 


        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(checkboxVisibility);

        return convertView;
    }

}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        adapter.setCheckboxVisibility(View.GONE);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Now call the setter method setCheckboxVisibility in  OnItemLongClickListener which will make the checkbox visible and you can select single or multiple rows.

```
 public OnItemLongClickListener myClickListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Assigning the item position to our global variable
        // So we can access it
        listView.performLongClick();
        adapter.setCheckboxVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       checkBox= (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setFocusable(true);
        checkBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);



        return true;
    }
};
```

Once you selected all the rows/row, you can delete them by by going through the list in which you will have saved the checked box states and deleting those whose  checked state was true.

```
 public void deleteSelected(View view) {

    if (listItems != null && !listItems.isEmpty()) {

        // Creating a new alert dialog to confirm the delete
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                .setTitle("Are you sure? ")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                int count=0;
                                ArrayList<Reflection> selectedItems = listItems;

                            for(int i=0;i<selectedItems.size();i++) {

                                if(selectedItems.get(i).isSelected()){

                                    DatabaseHelper.deleteNote(selectedItems.get(i).getId());
                                }




                            }
                                listItems = DatabaseHelper.getAllNotes("newones");
                                adapter.clear();
                                adapter.addAll(listItems);
                                if(checkBox!=null) {
                                    checkBox.setFocusable(false);
                                    checkBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                                }
                                adapter.setCheckboxVisibility(View.GONE);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                // When you press cancel, just close the
                                // dialog
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).show();


    }
```

Comment: Let me know if you still have any issues